# Docker ADD and Volume Conflict

Tags: docker

I cannot make a volume out of folders I use the add or copy command to create? Does anyone know why?

I am doing this on Windows 10, running windows nano server

Docker below 
C:Installs has a folder called spigot that is coped to the container
if I use VOLUME c:\installs\spigot  the container build failes
if I use VOLUME c:\installs\spigotX  the container build completes

I run the container with  -v:\mypcfoder:c:\installs\spigot if will not run
I run the container with  -v:\mypcfoder:c:\installs\spigotx it runs

```
# escape=`

FROM nano/java:1
MAINTAINER sscoleman@gmail.com

SHELL [ "powershell", "-Command" ]

ENV JAVA_MEM_START=32m `
    JAVA_MEM_MAX=4096m

COPY Installs c:\Installs
ADD RunSpigotServerEntry.ps1 /
ENTRYPOINT c:\RunSpigotServerEntry.ps1
EXPOSE 2525 25 21 25565 25575 14147 25000
#VOLUME c:\installs\spigot
```

Comment: Could you expand your question with your Dockerfile?

Comment: Updated with docker file

Answer (score 0):

Your v flag looks incorrect. There is a : between the flag and the paths. It should have a space.

Try

```
-v host_machine_dir:container_dir
```

See this link for further info
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only